# pmatrix not rendering correctly -- possibly a wileySix problem

Tags: amsmath

**Original post below**
A couple of people asked for a whole document:

```
\documentclass{wileySix}
\usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
 \[
 \mathbf{y}=
 \begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2
\end{pmatrix}\mbox{ and }
\boldsymbol{\mu}=\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_1 \\
\mu_2
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

This problem goes away when the documentclass is changed from `wileySix` to `article`. I will investigate.

**Original post**
Hi I would like to write the following expression in LaTeX using `pmatrix`
[image]

I can do this with standard older TeX:

```
\mathbf{y}=\left(\begin{array}{c} y_1 \\ y_2
\end{array} \right)  \mbox{ and }  \boldsymbol{\mu}=
\left(\begin{array}{c} \mu_1\\ \mu_2
\end{array} \right)
```

However, I think I should be able to do this much more neatly with using `pmatrix` from the `amsmath` package:

```
\mathbf{y}=
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\ y_2
\end{pmatrix}\mbox{ and }
\boldsymbol{\mu}=\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_1 \\ \mu_2
\end{pmatrix}
```

What I end up with in the rendered document is this

[image]

which clearly has problems. I'm running on MacTeX, but that has never caused me problems elsewhere. Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: please post a complete document that produces the image shown, so we can reproduce and debug.

Comment: this doesn't happen with `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{mathtools}` so you must be using some class or package that redefines what is provided by `amsmath`.  we can't help if we don't know what you're using.

Comment: The `wileysix` class redefines `\@array`, which confuses `amsmath`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton it happens when I use `\documentclass{wileySix}` From my naive scan through the class file, I can find very little dealing with mathematics (there is a macro for making symbols bold and something for equation numbering). However, it does only happen with this class.

Answer (score 6):

The `wileysix` class redefines `\@array` in a small but decisive detail:

#### LaTeX kernel definition

```
\def\@array[#1]#2{%
  \if #1t\vtop \else \if#1b\vbox \else \vcenter \fi\fi
  \bgroup
  \setbox\@arstrutbox\hbox{%
    \vrule \@height\arraystretch\ht\strutbox
           \@depth\arraystretch \dp\strutbox
           \@width\z@}%
  \@mkpream{#2}%
  \edef\@preamble{%
    \ialign \noexpand\@halignto
      \bgroup \@arstrut \@preamble \tabskip\z@skip \cr}%
  \let\@startpbox\@@startpbox \let\@endpbox\@@endpbox
  \let\tabularnewline\\%
    \let\par\@empty
    \let\@sharp##%
    \set@typeset@protect
    \lineskip\z@skip\baselineskip\z@skip
    \ifhmode \@preamerr\z@ \@@par\fi
    \@preamble}
```

#### `wileysix.cls` definition

```
\def\@array[#1]#2{%
  \if #1t\vtop \else \if#1b\vbox \else \vcenter \fi\fi
  \bgroup
  \setbox\@arstrutbox\hbox{%
    \vrule \@height\arraystretch\ht\strutbox
           \@depth\arraystretch \dp\strutbox
           \@width\z@}%
  \@mkpream{@{}#2@{}}%
  \edef\@preamble{%
    \ialign \noexpand\@halignto
      \bgroup \@arstrut \@preamble \tabskip\z@skip \cr}%
  \let\@startpbox\@@startpbox \let\@endpbox\@@endpbox
  \let\tabularnewline\\%
    \let\par\@empty
    \let\@sharp##%
    \set@typeset@protect
    \lineskip\z@skip\baselineskip\z@skip
    \ifhmode \@preamerr\z@ \@@par\fi
    \@preamble}
```

The difference is in the line

```
  \@mkpream{#2}%
```

that becomes

```
  \@mkpream{@{}#2@{}}%
```

so that no padding is added at the left and right of an `array`. On the other hand, `amsmath` manually fixes the padding in matrices, by adding a negative space between the fences and the matrix:

```
\renewenvironment{matrix}{%
  \matrix@check\matrix\env@matrix
}{%
  \endarray \hskip -\arraycolsep
}
\def\env@matrix{\hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols c}}
\renewenvironment{pmatrix}{%
  \left(%
  \matrix@check\pmatrix\env@matrix
}{
  \endmatrix\right)%
}
```

The `\hskip -\arraycolsep` are exactly the negative spaces I was talking about. The one on the right has its effect, because the standard preamble of a `matrix` is specified and the last column is not reached until the matrix has `\MaxMatrixCols` columns.

I find the redefinition in the class very silly: it is done *exactly* for the same purpose of `amsmath`, that is, not having a gap between the fences and the coefficients of the matrix. But the cure is worse than the disease.

I see no real problem in fixing the meaning of `\@array` to be the kernel one. Just remember to manually add `@{}` at either side of an `array` column specification in cases you use the environment for special matrices with non standard center alignment.

```
\documentclass{wileysix}
\usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@array}{\@mkpream{@{}#2@{}}}{\@mkpream{#2}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
 \[
 \mathbf{y}=
 \begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2
\end{pmatrix}\mbox{ and }
\boldsymbol{\mu}=\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_1 \\
\mu_2
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @JamesCurran Another way could be removing `\hskip -\arraycolsep` from the definition of `\env@matrix` and setting `\MaxMatrixCols` to 30, so you don't risk hitting the upper limit.